# Android Licensing Library Alternatives

Tags: android, licensing

I currently am using the licensing library in one of my apps. A lot of my users are complaining that the dialog tells them the app isn't licensed, when they paid for it.

A bad data connection is the issue: I myself have even got it on wifi. I noticed that I can open rom manager while in air plane mode;

So what are my alternatives? Ii'd like to switch to something that doesn't bother my customers so much but still protects my apps.

I set it up using the link below
http://www.droidforums.net/forum/android-app-developers/69899-market-license-easy-implementation-protect-your-apps.html

Comment: I have tried to make this a bit more readable by actually adding some punctuation instead of just 1 big sentence: please review if this is still roughly what you wanted to say, and try to write a bit more readable next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use the Google's library but use a custom ServerManagedPolicy.  The default ServerManagedPolicy will make request to the license server to check if the user is licensed, if it is licensed it will store a copy of the license locally (via preferences).  But this local copy has an expiry date, and after it expires it will again make another call to the license server to recheck.  All you need to do is modify this policy to have a longer expiry date.  You still need an internet connection when you first run the app, but most likely the user will have it since he bought the app.

The change is easy, make it in this method, in the if licensed statement, just use current date + one month for example.  Currently the code will use an expiry date that the license server sends.

```
public void processServerResponse(LicenseResponse response, ResponseData rawData) {

    // Update retry counter
    if (response != LicenseResponse.RETRY) {
        setRetryCount(0);
    } else {
        setRetryCount(mRetryCount + 1);
    }

    if (response == LicenseResponse.LICENSED) {
        // Update server policy data
        Map<String, String> extras = decodeExtras(rawData.extra);
        mLastResponse = response;
        setValidityTimestamp(extras.get("VT")); //MAKE CHANGE HERE
        setRetryUntil(extras.get("GT"));
        setMaxRetries(extras.get("GR"));
    } else if (response == LicenseResponse.NOT_LICENSED) {
        // Clear out stale policy data
        setValidityTimestamp(DEFAULT_VALIDITY_TIMESTAMP);
        setRetryUntil(DEFAULT_RETRY_UNTIL);
        setMaxRetries(DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES);
    }

    setLastResponse(response);
    mPreferences.commit();
}
```